# [C]Malloc problems

Tags: c, multithreading, segmentation-fault, malloc

I'm trying to write a program that uses some basic threading for an assignment. Below are the relevant snippets that I think are causing the problem.

The program runs fine with 25 or less threads but usually results in a segfault when 26 or more are used. This led me to think that my malloc statement were incorrect. Can anyone nudge me in the right direction? If you need more code to be posted, I'd be happy to provide it.

Also, these problems only come up when I run the program on my school's student machines. It appears to work fine my local machine. Might anyone know why?

Thanks for your time!

```
...

struct thread_args {
    struct bitmap *bm;
    double xmin;
    double xmax;
    double ymin;
    double ymax;
    int max;
    int start;
    int end;
};

...

int num_threads; //Given by user input
struct bitmap *bm = bitmap_create(500, 500); //All threads share the same bitmap
int i;
pthread_t *thread_id = malloc(num_threads * sizeof(*thread_id));
struct thread_args *args = malloc(num_threads * sizeof(*args));
for (i = 0; i < num_threads; i++) { 
    args[i].bm = bm;
    args[i].xmin = xcenter-scale;
    args[i].xmax = xcenter+scale;
    args[i].ymin = ycenter-scale;
    args[i].ymax = ycenter+scale;
    args[i].max = max;
    args[i].start = bitmap_height(bm) * i / num_threads;
    args[i].end = bitmap_height(bm) * (i + 1) / num_threads;

    pthread_create(&thread_id[i], NULL, compute_image, &args[i]);
}

for (i = 0; i < num_threads; i++) {
    pthread_join(thread_id[i], NULL);
}

...

void* compute_image(void *arg)
{
    struct thread_args* args = (struct thread_args*) arg;
    int i,j;
    int width = bitmap_width(args->bm);
    int height = bitmap_height(args->bm);

    // For every pixel in the image...

    for(j=args->start;j<args->end;j++) {
        for(i=0;i<width;i++) {
            // Determine the point in x,y space for that pixel.
            double x = args->xmin + i*(args->xmax-args->xmin)/width;
            double y = args->ymin + j*(args->ymax-args->ymin)/height;

            // Compute the iterations at that point.
            int iters = iterations_at_point(x,y,args->max);
            // Set the pixel in the bitmap.
            bitmap_set(args->bm,i,j,iters);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

...

valgrind log

==24919== 
==24919== HEAP SUMMARY:
==24919==     in use at exit: 1,000,000 bytes in 1 blocks
==24919==   total heap usage: 56 allocs, 55 frees, 1,018,884 bytes allocated
==24919== 
==24919== Searching for pointers to 1 not-freed blocks
==24919== Checked 87,112 bytes
==24919== 
==24919== 1,000,000 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 1
==24919==    at 0x4A069EE: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:270)
==24919==    by 0x401256: bitmap_create (bitmap.c:21)
==24919==    by 0x400CEC: main (mandel.c:103)
==24919== 
==24919== LEAK SUMMARY:
==24919==    definitely lost: 1,000,000 bytes in 1 blocks
==24919==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==24919==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==24919==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==24919==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==24919== 
==24919== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 6 from 6)
--24919-- 
--24919-- used_suppression:      4 U1004-ARM-_dl_relocate_object
--24919-- used_suppression:      2 glibc-2.5.x-on-SUSE-10.2-(PPC)-2a
==24919== 
==24919== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 6 from 6)
```

Edit: Added compute_image code and valgrind log although the log is missing the error messages it was showing earlier today. The 1,000,000 bytes lost is something I know about.

Comment: There are several debugging tools that will tell you exactly where things are failing. Just google "c debugging tools". Debugging is a skill you will need post graduation

Comment: Shall we assume all your threads are supposed to share the *same* bitmap? Because they do. And if you think the actual *thread proc* is relevant here, you're right.

Comment: stdlib calls may fail. You should check the return values of your malloc() calls for NULL before using them.

Comment: @redFIVE I tried using GDB and valgrind but I _think_ that they're telling me that the malloc is not allocating the proper amount of space.

Comment: @WhozCraig Ah yes, all the threads share the same bitmap. They work on separate sets of data and parts of the image so there's no race condition.

Comment: Post the valgrind summary report *as an addendum to the question please*. And fair warning you're probably going to end up posting `compute_image` as well, so get ready for that.

Comment: `struct bitmap *bm; ` is uninitialised. `bitmap_height(bm) ` will probably dereference it.

Comment: @wildplasser I'm somewhat assuming all of the locals he's not showing besides by-decl are initialized *somewhere*. I.e `num_threads` would be in a similar boat. but you never know without real code, to be sure.

Comment: Could be. Too little information. I get triggered by the first obvious misstake, the rest is irrelevant to me.

Comment: @wildplasser Sorry about the confusion, `num_threads` and `bm` are previously initialized.

Comment: Valgrind isn't reporting any overruns, which it very-likely would if you were walking over the ends of your allocated space. The only thing it is reporting is the 1MB leak (which I assume you know about and you're likely allocating (4*w*h) bytes for your bitmap. or close to it. Odd that your `bm` *members* don't appear to be included in that calculation of space. Anyway, I was hoping to see an overrun in valgrind, but none appears to be present.

Comment: Don't feel sorry. Post real code instead, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that `pthread_create` is not returning an error. The machine has a global limit on the number of threads that can be spawned, and is probably fluctuating close to that limit. If you fail to spawn a thread, you will have a garbage `pthread_t`, which will likely cause `pthread_join` to blow up.

Comment: I replaced `pthread_create(&thread_id[i], NULL, compute_image, &args[i]);` with `while (pthread_create(&thread_id[i], NULL, compute_image, &args[i]) != 0);` and it appears to be working now. Is this what you meant? Of course, I plan to use errno and strerror at some point.

Comment: I was just suggesting that you check for errors.  I would have printed an error message and exited instead of spinning until it succeeded.  I would guess that everyone is working on the same assignment, and creating lots of threads.  By spinning, your program is going to wait for someone else's program to finish and free up resources.  However, if you're unlucky, your program could spin indefinitely.